# Creating a new Class Library Template for .NET Standard 2.0 does not copy source files

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

This issue arises when creating a new template for the Class Library in `.Net Standard` 2.0 using automatic `VS2017` tools. When creating a new project from that template, source files (.cs) will not be copied.

Although I need complex Templates, will use the simplest case to explain the problem.

Create a new template: New Project in `VS2017`, choose Class library `.NET Standard`. With this "empty" project, create the template, click `Project>Export Template> chose the created project, and then finish.`

Create new project from the recently created template: Add new project, choose the new template, and accept.

The resulting new project does not have the source file (.cs) of that project.

It is obviously a problem since doing exactly the same with a Class library that is `.NET Framework` works fine.

```
Classlibrary1.csproj

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
  <PropertyGroup>    
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>  
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

MyTemplate.vstemplate

<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
<TemplateData>
  <Name>ClassLibrary1</Name>
  <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
  <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  <ProjectSubType>
  </ProjectSubType>
  <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
  <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
  <DefaultName>ClassLibrary1</DefaultName>
  <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
  <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
  <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
  <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
  <Project TargetFileName="ClassLibrary1.csproj" File="ClassLibrary1.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Class1.cs">Class1.cs</ProjectItem>
  </Project>
</TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I tried different "solutions" but they do not work for me. 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/37226/new-project-missing-files-from-exported-project-te.html

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/605

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new template, `Visual Studio` saves it in `C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\` but also in `C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\My Exported Templates\`, however `Visual Studio` reads templates only from \Templates.

The problem is that as default the parameter of the template **CreateInPlace** is supposed to be true. But for `.Net Standard` you must set the value. To do so, go to the Folder `\Templates\`, find the template and unzip it, erase the zip. Open the template file and add the value:

```
MyTemplate.vstemplate
  ....
  <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
</TemplateData>
....
```

It should already work. Do not try to zip the template again, will not be read properly from zip.

If anyone has a better answer, please share.

Comment: Your answer fixed some completely irrelevant problem for me but thanks a lot anyway. :D